# Can't format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, momentjs

I am trying to format a array of dates using `moment.js` but I get an error stating

> dayOfWeek.format is not a function

I am correctly imported

```
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('isoWeek');
var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('isoWeek');

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}




var week = days.map(function(dayOfWeek, i){
  console.log(dayOfWeek);
  dayOfWeek.format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY")
});
```

Comment: Sam, see my post, it explains why your code fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code will fail because `dayOfWeek` is not `moment` object.

To check if your variable is `moment` object use `.isMoment`:

`moment.isMoment(dayOfWeek)`.

To fix your problem simply replace

```
dayOfWeek.format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY")
```

with

```
moment(dayOfWeek).format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY")
```

You are also missing `return` statement inside `.map` function.

**Working example:**

```js
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('isoWeek');
var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('isoWeek');

var days = [];
var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    days.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}




var week = days.map(function(dayOfWeek, i){
  return moment(dayOfWeek).format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY")
});

console.log(week);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your in depth answer!

Answer (score 3):

`moment().format()` function **usage is not correct**.

Current is:

```
dayOfWeek.format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY")
```

Change to:

```
moment(dayOfWeek).format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY")
```

Check here for more information: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

Answer (score 1):

```
dayOfWeek = moment(dayOfWeek).format("dddd, DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, You can also do this

```js
var currentDate = moment(new Date()); // pass your date obj here.
console.log(currentDate.format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss')); // later simply do this.
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.22.2/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```